# Microsoft Graph API cannot write to ExtensionAttributes

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have 2 Microsoft O365 tenants, one for my lab and one for production.
Using the graph API I managed to successfully write values to extensionAttribute1 on my lab tenant but I got the following error when attempting to write to the production tenant.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/xxxx@contoso.com
Request Body:
{
  "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
     "extensionAttribute1": "BlahBlah"
  }
}
```

> Error: Unable to update the specified properties for objects that have originated within an external service.

The difference between the 2 tenants is that the production tenant was built by AD syncing with our old on premise AD and the lab tenant was created from scratch in the cloud.  The legacy on premise AD and AD sync machines were decommissioned about a year ago.
Is there something that I can do to my production tenant, either on a global or per user basis, to remove the read-only limitation on extensionAtributes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For an `onPremisesSyncEnabled` user, the source of authority for this set of properties is the on-premises and is read-only. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).

Comment: Yes, as @AllenWu updated you can't update the read-only property, hence you're getting the above error.

Comment: Did you check the `onPremisesSyncEnabled` property of the user you are trying to update?

Comment: I appreciate that this was once onprem, however the onprem servers no longer exist and we only have AD in the cloud, I was wondering if there is a way to let AAD understand this and hence remove the read-only property?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, it looks like Azure still treats your users as enabling local synchronization.

It is strongly recommended that you [raise an Azure support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to let the Azure backend check your tenant status and provide further assistance.